# Session-scoped bean has dependency set to null when written in Kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

Using spring boot 2.3.4, kotlin 1.3.72.

I've got a session-scoped bean that Spring is instantiating with a null dependency, which obviously results in a NPE when it is executed. I created a sample project to reproduce the behavior. **The equivalent code works in Java.** UPDATE: The below works if I only convert the MessageWriterService to Java.

Here's my configuration class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class SessionScopeKotlinApplication {

    @Bean
    fun messageWriter() = MessageWriter()

    @Bean
    @SessionScope
    fun messageWriterSvc(writer: MessageWriter) = MessageWriterService(writer)

}
```

The MessageWriter and the MessageWriterService

```
class MessageWriter {
    fun write() = println("message written!")
}

open class MessageWriterService(private val writer: MessageWriter) {

    private var written = false

    fun writeIfNotWritten() {
        if (!written) {
            writer.write()
            written = true
        } else {
            println("** message already written, not writing again **")
        }
    }
}
```

And then I have a controller that calls the MessageWriterService:

```
@RestController
class MessageWriterController(private val writerService: MessageWriterService) {
    @GetMapping("/write")
    fun write() {
        writerService.writeIfNotWritten()
    }
}
```

As soon as I call the controller method, I get the stacktrace below (abbreviated). The point of failure is the call to the writer, which is actually null.

```
2020-10-13 07:37:41.919 ERROR 9184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.example.sessionscopekotlin.MessageWriterService.writeIfNotWritten(SessionScopeKotlinApplication.kt:32) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.sessionscopekotlin.MessageWriterController.write(SessionScopeKotlinApplication.kt:44) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
```

Comment: It would help if you highlighted the line where the NPE occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it seems that Spring can't autowire the `Writer` for you here:

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
class SessionScopeKotlinApplication {

    @Bean
    fun messageWriter() = MessageWriter()

    @Bean
    @SessionScope
    fun messageWriterSvc(writer: MessageWriter) = MessageWriterService(writer)

}
```

The solution for this is to call the bean function like this:

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
class SessionScopeKotlinApplication {

    @Bean
    fun messageWriter() = MessageWriter()

    @Bean
    @SessionScope
    fun messageWriterSvc() = MessageWriterService(messageWriter())

}
```

You should also use the `prototype` scope if you don't want the same `Writer` to be returned for each call.

Comment: Sure enough, that fixed it. I did the same style of autowiring in Java, and it worked. Weird that it doesn't in Kotlin. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: You can also use the `@Autowired` annotation I think.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting finding. If you don't want to create new MessageWriter for every session the following approach could help:

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
class SessionScopeKotlinApplication {

    @Bean
    fun messageWriter() = MessageWriter()

}

@Service
@SessionScope
class MessageWriterService(private val writer: MessageWriter) {

    private var written = false

    fun writeIfNotWritten() {
        if (!written) {
            writer.write()
            written = true
        } else {
            println("** message already written, not writing again **")
        }
    }
}
```

So you basically switch from `@Bean` annotation to direct `@Service` declaration. But I can imagine some cases where you would like to use the `@Bean` annotation explicit.